# Getting 400 Bad request on sending request to iam.amazonaws.com

Tags: apex, httprequest, url, amazon

I trying to create user from Apex in AWS/IAM. For that I have created URL according to description given aws in its documentation and I am doing this with get method. But issue I am facing is that,my code generate a valid url for creating user in AWS/iam but when I send the request with Http send() method it always gives me 400 bad request.

How come I know that my apex code generates a valid URL ? so, for that I used my generated URL with Postman REST Client to send the request and from here user get created on AWS/iam. So, my created URL is valid.

So, I want to know how it is possible that same URL create the user on AWS/iam from postman client and gives bad request in apex ?

How does http.send() method send the http request in apex ?

How can I trace that what request is sent by http.send() with any tool like Live Http header ?